# I want to hide ul item when clicked on list item without effecting its functionality! Check description for more info

Tags: css, angular

I have created a `<ul>` with some `<li>`, I used these list items to navigate user as shown in the image. Now the problem is I want to hide the ul when user clicks on any li.
An important note is I used angular routerLink functionality to navigate user between different pages.

I tried to use `:active` and it works fine but It broke the navigating functionality, I don't know why, so what would be a better idea?

Except this issue, everything is working fine.

[image]

I have the following code:

```
<div class="account-wrapper">
        <button routerLink="/auth/login" *ngIf="authenticated" class="account-btn">
          <i class="material-icons">
            account_circle
          </i>
        </button>
        <ul class="account-group">

          <li class="account-group-item">My Profile</li>
          <li class="account-group-item" routerLink="/cart">
            <i class="material-icons">
              shopping_cart
            </i>Cart</li>

          <li class="account-group-item">
            <i class="material-icons">
              payment
            </i>My Orders</li>

          <li class="account-group-item">
            <i class="material-icons">
              favorite
            </i>Whishlist</li>

          <li class="account-group-item" (click)="onLogout()">
            <i class="material-icons">
              exit_to_app
            </i>Logout</li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Css code**

```
.account-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.account-btn {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.account-btn>i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.account-group {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: -90px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.account-btn:hover~.account-group > .account-group-item ,
.account-group:hover > .account-group-item{
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.account-group > .account-group-item:active {
    transform: scale(.9, .9);
}

.account-btn:hover~.account-group,
.account-group:hover {
    pointer-events: initial;
}

.account-group-item {
  width: 180px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: .5rem 0 .5rem .8rem;
  font-size: .9rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform .2s ease;
}

.account-group-item>i {
  font-size: 1rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: .3rem;
}

.account-group-item:hover {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify if my understanding is correct.
On click of list item you want to navigate to some other route and close the menu item and that menu item is present in common header which will be present in all the pages.

Comment: yes sir, exactly

Comment: Try to add routing and show and hide in Js rather hiding using css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding as i asked in comment.
On click of list item you want to navigate to some other route and close the menu item and that menu item is present in common header which will be present in all the pages

Problem here lies in this line

> I tried to use :active and it works fine but It broke the navigating functionality, I don't know why, so what would be a better idea?
>
> Now when you are using CSS to hide the your menu, your menu is getting hidden before your click event is triggered, that's why your navigation is breaking

To fix this don't hide your menu only using css, rather than this call a function on click event as you did for logout functionality in that function hide the menu. Either using a boolean flag or by adding and removing css class.

I hope this should be enough to solve your problem
If you want further explanation you can share a working fiddle where i will fix your problem